# Setup multi languages wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications, blogs

I need to setup a blog using wordpress engine but i need it support multi languages (3 languages), currently i am thinking of using custom field to identify the language of current post though i knew thats not a best practices, does anyone has better suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I've tested 2 plugins that both looked very promising: [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) and [Gengo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gengo/)

qTranslate works by adding inputs for all used languages for each post, Gengo used separate posts and links them in a "post Y is a translation of post X" way, which I preferred much (because it allowed me to not translate everything) and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the xlanguage plugin and I am happy with it.
[xlanguage site](http://hellosam.net/project/xlanguage)

Answer (score 0):

I fi i remember well, wordpress uses a gettext "customization" library to translate itself.
I think you can make some options based on a session variable, about the translation files you're going to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try using plugin wordpress WPML.