# Wordpress multilanguage plugin

Tags: internationalization, wordpress, multilingual

I have a blog on Wordpress in which I need to serve contents in several different languages. I don't want to translate the articles, I just want to have some in each of the languages and just have a way of switching between them. I was looking for a wordpress plugin that allows such functionality but so far I found only [xLanguage](http://hellosam.net/project/xlanguage) but it's not what I intend to use if for, although it's pretty close.

What this plugin allows is to have a contents in the post that is localized for one specific language and it's not displayed in other languages. However it's main flaws are

- you cannot translate post titles
- if I define the post in just some of the languages my site supports the post will appear blank (I would like that it won't appear at all in this language)

Does anyone knows if there is a plugin that I could use or I should start thinking of developing one myself. As I mentioned I don't really need a translation functionality, just the ability to mark the post to appear in only one selected language.

I guess I could also set up several instances of wordpress, each for every language but then I will need to replicate every configuration change in all the instances and that's something I would really like to avoid.

#### Update

Actually I just noticed that I can hide untranslated messages by specifying a parameter in options but there is still one problem.

The rest of the page (links, other text generated by Wordpress) doesn't get translated while switching the page. So I have my contents translated by still see default language in navigation etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gengo looked interesting, but development seems to have stopped.

But the qtranslate plugin ([author's page](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/), [plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)) offers the things you need.  It not only manages article translations but also switches the complete site (“user interface”) language.

Articles (including titles) can be stored in several languages.  If you need a translation elsewhere (i.e. a widget title), you can use special markup (language tags): `<!--:en-->english<!--:--><!--:de-->Deutsch<!--:-->`

I'm still testing it myself, but it mostly works alright.  There may be surprised (e.g. date fields), so better test it on a offline copy of your site.

Also, check this older [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172138/setup-multi-languages-wordpress)

Comment: Unfortunately qTranslate is full of bugs, the author doesn't reply to emails and it doesn't integrate with other plugins like ACF. http://wpml.org/ seems a better option but I haven't tested it (yet).

Comment: I didn't encounter that many bugs in qtranslate, but there *are* some issues, e.g. if you have separate RSS feeds for languages, the respective GUIDs are not unique.  (I ran into the problem when bilingual posts showed up only once on geobulletin.org.) I posted a simple fix to the forum, but didn't get any feedback.

Integration problems: JetPack Twitter updates don't understand bilingual posts / titles. However, whom to blame? JetPack because it disregards translation, or qTranslate because it doesn't patch JetPack? IMO As long as Wordpress isn't multiling, we'll run into such problems. :-(

Comment: qTranslate didn't make me suffer enough yet to want to pay for wpml.org...  It seems that wpml offers quite some more features, esp. for bigger sites.

Answer (score 3):

I have built several multilingual sites and I use the WPML plugin and have found it to be best option out there. http://wpml.org/