# WordPress / jQuery - Add Text into Permalink using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, permalinks

I have been trying to use the answer at [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) to modify a WordPress permalink, however I am not having much luck and need assistance.

I am trying to modify the WordPress Permalink on one Hyperlink, across all pages on the site.

```
<a id="language" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">German</a>
```

Lets say the permalink is `http://www.wordpress-site.com/about-us/`

I want to modify it, using jQuery to read `http://www.wordpress-site.com/ger/about-us/`

What would my jQuery code need to be in order to accomplish this?  It needs to work dynamically, across all pages on the site, identifying `http://www.wordpress-site.com/whatever/` in the `a#language` on all pages, and replacing it with `http://www.wordpress-site.com/ger/whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a#language').attr('href', function() {
      return this.href.replace(/^(http:\/\/www\.wordpress-site\.com)(.*)/, "$1/ger$2");
   });
});​​​
```

I don´t know your setup but is it really necessary to change the URL on the client side? IMHO this kind of URL rewriting is typically a task for the server.

Comment: In principle, yes. But I don´t know WordPress well enough to say if there is an easy way to implement this. Maybe there is a plugin which suits your needs. There are some related questions: [Setup multi languages wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172138/setup-multi-languages-wordpress), [Wordpress multilanguage plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513346/wordpress-multilanguage-plugin)

Comment: OK.  I'm not really looking for multi language, the above was just an example of the type of thing I want to accomplish - injecting text into a URL/Permalink.   WordPress isn't flexible enough to allow that, I know it very well hence why I wanted to do it with jQuery.  I tried your demo code above but it wouldn't work.  Do you have a jsFiddle for it?