# Multi-lingual wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How can I create a perminalink structure like this: `/%language%/%category%/` and make it recognised by WordPress?

I don't want to use the language plugin, instead I want to code it myself.

Comment: Creating the permalink would not be the hard part, it will be modifying WordPress to add the language to the post query.
Are you creating a custom field to add a language and are you creating multiple posts in each language?
I'm thinking you'll have to create at least a minimal plugin in order to run your custom query.

Comment: i am going to store the languages in different csv file and embed to the html using a key and out languages depends on the /%language%/ value, the problems is how to set and get this language value and modifying the rewrite rule?

Comment: How many languages do you plan on using?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172138/setup-multi-languages-wordpress) last month titled [Setup multi languages wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172138/setup-multi-languages-wordpress). I've started to use [WPML](http://wpml.org/) and it's showing promise.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Apache `mod_rewrite` module.

Also, I remember reading in the WPML issue forum (now blocked) that it is impossible to get the permalinks to be exactly the same (besides lang code), because this is a fundamental restriction in how WordPress works.

So you could not have both:

```
mysite.com/en/food/mypost/

mysite.com/jp/food/mypost/
```

You'd have to make it like:

```
mysite.com/en/food/mypost/

mysite.com/jp/food/jp-mypost/
```

This is pretty annoying.